# Fog on camera case with chest mount

Tags: camera

I've got a chest mount for my camera (sony hdr-as15, if it's important). I went on a race last Sunday - it was like +15-17 Celsius. After about an hour of riding I've noticed that the case is all foggy and the picture turned from this
[image] into this: [image]

So, what can be done to prevent this?

Comment: Was the fog inside or outside the camera housing? If outisde it's probably getting sprayed up off the ground, or from riding through mist/low cloud.  A rinse would help (assumign the camera is waterproof)

Comment: @ChrisH - from the inside. I mean between the camera and it's case

Comment: Then I suggest either the case wasn't sealed, or was sealed with moisture inside and your body heat evaporated that moisture, which then condensed at the coolest part. I've seen that with a camera in a waterproof case used for kayaking, when it got damp inside the case one day and fogged up the next

Comment: you could also ask on photo or video stack-exchange channels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally I would not expect this at 15C-17C, its something that happens at 5C.

Presuming the case is sealed and was dry before closing it up, the cause is because the inside of the case was warm with high humidity before being taken into colder air. Most likely the warm air inside your home is damp, or the case has been sealed up for a while. When taken outside, the air in the case cooled, and was no longer able to hold the water vapour so it  condensed on the coldest part - the lens that points away from you as that gets no body heat.

To prevent this, leave the camera case open when in storage, and store in a dry location (stuffed in you gear bag with your damp cloths and shoes form the last ride is really not a good idea). If the temperature changes is high - e.g when I head out on 0C degree morning, I leave the camera and case open in cold outside air before sealing it up for the ride, ideally for at least an hour.

An alternate, if conditions are suitable, is to use a non-waterproof case that has massive slots  to allow airflow.

Comment: A bag of rice is what scuba divers and others use to desiccate their camera equipment before going under.

Comment: There are those little silica-gel bags that come in the packaging of some equipment. They can even be re-used after they have been heated to release the absorbed water.

Answer (score 1):

Go-pro cases are notoriously lacking in spare space for rice or silica gel sachets.

So Gopro themselves make an "anti-fog insert" which is labelled as a "HUMONITOR"

Details are at https://shop.gopro.com/APAC/accessories-2/anti-fog-inserts/AHDAF-302.html  but they look like a lot thinner than a silica sack and can fit between the camera and the housing.

Downside, they're not cheap.

Comment: Had a quick search on google, it looks possible to buy desiccant paper a lot cheaper than the branded product.